# Accessing python container's parent object

Tags: python, class, object, containers, parent

I need to create a containers that can access its children but also its parent. 
Here is a simple example of how I was thinking to do that :

```
import numpy as np
import gc


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.parent = None
        self.child = []
        self.name = name
        self.mem_tracer = np.ones(10 ** 6)

    def append(self, obj):
        assert(isinstance(obj, Node))
        self.child.append(obj)
        obj.parent = self
```

But, with that I have a memory issue when I try to delete a Node (note that the attribute mem_tracer is just here to be able to see if the object has been removed from the memory or not)

This code shows the problem (the memory state at each line is given) :

```
print 'start'                    # 16.96Mb

a = Node('0')                    # 24.79Mb

a.append(Node('0/0'))            # 32.61Mb
a.append(Node('0/1'))            # 40.42Mb

a.child[0].append(Node('0/0/0')) # 48.24Mb
a.child[0].append(Node('0/0/1')) # 56.06Mb

a.child[1].append(Node('0/1/0')) # 63.87Mb
a.child[1].append(Node('0/1/1')) # 71.69Mb

del a.child[0]                   # 71.69Mb

gc.collect()                     # 48.24Mb
```

The garbage collector is not able to collect the deleted object as a reference to it still exists in its children (while they are not referenced anywhere anymore).
We can see at the last line, that an explicit call to `gc.collect` solves the problem but I would prefer to get rid of it as it is very time consuming!

So is there an other way to access the parent container than storing it into an attribute?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `weakref.ref` to store the reference to the parent.  That's not enough to keep the object alive from the garbage collector, but it is enough to give you a reference to the object back if it hasn't been garbage collected.  (but I haven't thought through all the implications of that yet ... e.g. if your objects are safe from the GC if you only hang on to a reference to the head of the linked list for example).

Comment: Thank you so much! ``weakref`` solves everything! No memory leaks anymore!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- manually delete `obj.parent`
- use `weakref` to keep a pseudo-reference to the parent.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref) for more info on `weakref`.